# JavaFX ComboBox styling (disabled psuedo-class)

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have this (simple) combination of fxml/css and java. The combobox in question (operationSelector) is indeed disabled, but it's opacity is 0.4 (the default for disabled nodes instead of 1.0). Printing this.operationSelector.getStyleClass() shows that the singleton-combo-box class is indeed part of its style class. I tried disabling all style classes but singleton-combo-box and STILL the opacity is 0.4 when disabled. Does anything obviously wrong jump out? (By the way, I am using Java 8u40 early access)

In FXML:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="operationSelector" styleClass="singleton-combo-box" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
```

In CSS:

```
.singleton-combo-box:disabled {
   -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
.singleton-combo-box .list-cell:disabled {
  -fx-opacity: 1.0;
  -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

In Java:

```
    @FXML private ComboBox<String> operationSelector;

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
            this.operationSelector.setDisable(true);
    }
```

Here is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lyb1.jpg

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you checked with Scene Builder? If you mark your combo as disable it should have the opacity set to 1.0 (with a blue mark). Otherwise you are not loading the proper css file

Comment: Knowing that this worked for you made me dig deeper into what could be causing this. I realized that this combo-box was actually in a Dialog, which (even though `initOwner` was used to make the Dialog owned by the scene _with_ the style-sheet set) did not have the style-sheet explicitly set on the dialog, like so:

    `newProfileConditionDialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource(MainWindow.getUniversalStylesheet()).toExternalForm());`

Then the style was correct for the combo-box inside of the newProfileConditionDialog.

Comment: You can use `StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet()` to register a global Stylesheet. But it is internal API..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by eckig there is a way to do this using the private API (com.sun.*):

```
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(url)
```

After a bit of research I found a suggestion by Jonathan Giles (UI Controls technical lead in JavaFX team at Oracle) where he showed a way to do this without direct use of the private API:

```
 Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(url)
```

This method should be the best way to set a universal style-sheet for the entire application (all stages and scenes).